# Why flutter youtube_extractor package not working?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube, youtube-api

I have tried [this](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_extractor#-readme-tab-) package and all other packages available but I cannot get the youtube direct media link so that I can download the files.

Is there any other way to download youtube videos through URL or is there any other working package??

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: have you tried [Youtube_Explode](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart) ?

Comment: @Adnankarim I am getting error in getting video stream. i Have tried this example https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart#get-video-mediastream

Comment: I am getting Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. this error